# Hide One2many field Conditionally Odoo/OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I am creating an option called Master Account within the customer portion of an Odoo 8.0 setup. If selected, it will set another account as the grandparent. This is useful for companies/customers who have multiple locations, but just one billing center. I was able to apply this functionality, but now I do not want to display the option to set a master account to a company that is already set as someone's master.

I have tried the following and it does not work:

PYTHON

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    related_partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Master Account')
    related_partner_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner', 'Master Account')
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="base_view_partner_demo_inherit">
            <field name="name">res.partner.form.demo</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="website" position="after">
                    <field name="related_partner_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('related_partner_ids','>', '0')]}"/>
               <field name="related_partner_ids"  invisible="1"/>
               <label string="Master Account" attrs="{'invisible': [['related_partner_id', '!=', False]]}"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm brand new to Odoo.

Answer (score 6):

Try following,

```
from openerp import models, fields, api, _

class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    related_partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Master Account')
    related_partner_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner', 'related_partner_id', 'Master Account')
```

**One2many** required inverse field id as well. 
And set attrs like this,

```
<field name="related_partner_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('related_partner_ids','!=', False)]}"/>
```

Or You should write like this

```
<field name="related_partner_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('related_partner_ids','!=', [])]}"/>
```

For **Many2many** fields, attrs should be applied in following manner.

```
<field name="m2m_field" attrs="{'invisible': [('m2m_field','=', [(6,0,[])])]}"/>
```

Comment: Getting errors using the following lines of XML:
    <field name="website" position="after">
                    <field name="related_partner_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('related_partner_ids','!=', False)]}"/>
               <field name="related_partner_ids"  invisible="1"/>
               <label string="Master Account" attrs="{'invisible': [['related_partner_id', '!=', False]]}"/>

Comment: What is the error ?, you need to update your module as well, because there are changes in columns structure  also.